# How get the disk transfer rate, in percetage usage, for cmd/batch?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, command-line, batch

I need to know when the hdd is a bottleneck, to improve my batch code on Windows 10
I am looking for a command line for cmd/batch similar to this one, but that helps me to know the disk load percentage. (This is not about the disk space).

wmic cpu get loadpercentage

thank you